# Simple scroll-to-top script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fade

Agh, frustrating me so much. I'm trying to use a simple fadein scroll to top script but it just won't work on my site, maybe there's a conflict?

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollup{
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
left: 15%;
display: none;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat;
z-index: 5000;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    }); 

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Website: http://kaye.at/test/

Comment: you have a js error saying jquery is not defined. include jquery.js before you run your script.

Comment: Blonde moment, thanks. I was sure I thought of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import a [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) library before `$(function(){` call.

Add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` inside your `<head>` element.

Also, `.no-touch .vs-container { overflow-x: hidden; }` prevents firing the scroll event on the window document.

Comment: It is on the same page.

Comment: It seems like another script is blocking the scroll event, your javascript is correct...

Comment: Yeah it seems to be the modernizr.custom.js but I'm not sure how to fix it argh.

Comment: it isn't... it's actually your CSS code. `.no-touch .vs-container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}` prevents firing the event on the window document. Remove it or change your CSS